# Is it better to use the same form of verbs in one sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, rhetoric

I heard a sentence form BBC:

> It CAN MEAN to extend, continue or progress beyond a particular thing or MEANS to extend or continue further than that thing or point.

Why not both "can mean"?

Is it better to use the same form of verbs in one sentence?

---

The context is quite simple. It's a BBC English-learning program teaching "behind" & "beyond". I'm using it as an intensive listening material.

The "it" refers "beyond", and the sentence explains the meanings of "beyond".

@Robusto suggested dropping the "means". I agree and think it may be the best.

Comment: I would probably strike the second *means* in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes be difficult to interpret the meaning of phrases without context. It appears that in this example, "can mean" and "means" hold different definitions.

The phrase "can mean" does what we might think: it conveys meaning.

The other phrase, "means," could also be written as "a method"

For example, a car is a *means* of transportation, and a phone is a *means* of communication.

---

Therefore, whatever the sentence is discussing could be either "to extend beyond a thing" or "a method to extend beyond a thing."

Comment: I added the context.

Answer (score 1):

The style rule of [*parallelism*](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism/) does suggest that, when comparing two things or making a list of similar things, it is better to use the same verb tense or part of speech for all the elements.  Examples:

> I prefer **dining out** at a restaurant to **eating in** at home.
>
> His favorite activities are **running** marathons, **feeding** pigeons, and **dancing** the waltz.
>
> At the meeting you will be expected to **listen** carefully, **take** notes, and **keep** an eye out for anything unusual.

In your example it's not clear whether these are two parallel conditions.  The speaker could be saying the item *can* mean A, or else it *does* mean B.  Another example:

> I **can meet** you at 2 this afternoon, or **let's meet** at 4.

Here there are two separate possibilities.  The first I present as an *option*, and the second as a *suggestion*.

In addition, parallelism only really applies in formal communication.  On a more informal, unscripted television program, these kind of style rules are often overlooked as commentators speak naturally.